# Strange things happened when using \boldsymbol after loading mathspec package

Tags: mathspec, boldsymbol

Basic info:

- OS version: Windows 10
- TeX version: TeX Live 2019
- Editor: TeXstudio 2.12.14

Detailed issue:

Hi all. In order to use the font "Times New Roman", I load the package "mathspec". However, when using "\boldsymbol", the output result is strange, just like the following picture:

[image: yV8Ygx.md.jpg]

My code is:

```
%! Tex program = xelatex (mandatory, required by mathspec package) 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% for using Times New Roman
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}

% for using \boldsymbol
\usepackage{bm}

\title{A test for \text{"boldsymbol"}}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
For example, $ \boldsymbol{A}+B+z $.

\end{document}
```

Is there any conflicts between the packages "bm" and "mathspec"? How to deal with this issue? Thanks to all.

Comment: Welcome! No, unfortunately `mathspec` doesn't support math versions, so you get “poor man's bold”, which is definitely unsuitable for serious typesetting. Why not using `unicode-math` and the STIX Two fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `mathspec` doesn't support math versions, so you get “poor man's bold”, that is, the character is typeset three times with slight offsets.

There are better ways to use Times also for math.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{A test for ``boldsymbol''}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

For example, $ \mathbfit{A}+B+z $.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. However,  I need the font to be exactly the same as "Times New Roman", so I must use "mathspec".

Comment: @latex_lover Not sure what you mean by “exactly the same". There are so many clones of Times!

Comment: My supervisor required that the font of the paper must be "Times New Roman", and can not be the clones of Times  :(

Comment: @latex_lover then use times for the text and stix only for the math.